# At what stage of research career one can write a 'tutorial article'?

Tags: publications

I learned from [this thread](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3628/22560) that review articles are often written by experienced scholars, but I wonder if a graduate student can publish a tutorial as his/her first publication? For instance, [Tutorial on Variational Autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05908).

Comment: I think once you have a 'better' viewpoint or intuitive explanation, you can write a tutorial.  For example, https://betterexplained.com/  explains basic maths very well.  Another example is the 3Blue1Brown YouTube channel.  End of the day, a tutorial is useful if it helps a reader grok an area.  If you think there is a good 'path' that a reader can use to enter an area or simplify a seemingly complex idea/topic, by all means,  write about it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I find that a relatively inexperienced (but not naive) person can write a valuable tutorial for novices. The reason is that they may remember how hard it was to get started and, especially, to gain insight. More experienced people, especially experts, often lose the sense of how difficult it once was.

I once specifically wrote a treatise on a topic I was learning in order to capture the wonder of it all along with the difficulty and what to look out for. It turned out pretty well.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the 'curse of knowledge' discussions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not up to you (or a collection of random people on the 'net) to decide if the tutorial paper you want to write is up to your target venue's standards. In any case, you not being one of the stars of the field should not be a criterion to accept/reject. Sure, a rockstar has probably a wider perspective and experience teaching the stuff, so they'll probably (possibly?) write it up better.